# How can I open a Word document read-only from Perl?

Tags: perl, ms-word, ole

Is there any method within Perl which would allow me to get the object in a read only mode,
so as to avoid the dialog that pops up if the file is locked by another user?

```
$document = Win32::OLE->GetObject("$docFile")
    or die "can't open $docFile";
```

Comment: If you want the text only, you might try running `antiword` or the like on it. I'm not sure if `antiword` builds on Windows, however. It's my preferred method for dealing with Word docs on OSX and Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you're doing it wrong. `GetObject` just opens an object with the default behavior. You should create the `Word.Application` object:

```
 my $word = Win32::OLE->new( 'Word.Application' );
```

Then use the `Documents` collection `Open` method with the named parameter `ReadOnly`. Like so:

```
 $doc = $word->Documents->Open( { FileName => $document_path,
                                , ReadOnly => 1
                                } );
```

Read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb216319.aspx for the syntax for `Documents.Open`

Comment: I will experiment with that.
Thank you.

Comment: A very high quality answer.
Thank you.